# Scala filter list on condition

Tags: scala, seq

I have a Seq of Student object who have scored marks in different subjects.
e.g.

```
Vector(Students(1,Math,40),Students(1,English,60), Students(1,Science,55), Students(2,Math,80),Students(2,English,60), Students(2,Science,55),Students(3,Math,40),Students(3,English,60), Students(3,Science,30))
```

I want list of students who have scored more than 50 in all subject. For now I am doing it by iterating , putting the value in map and checking rechecking as we do in java. How can we do it in Scala?

Comment: `groupBy` will be helpful for separating the `Students(1, ...)` items from the `Students(2, ...)` items (and so on)

Comment: @SethTisue actually author is not asking about how to group the students. it's about how to put a condition on each element of list.

Comment: @RamanMishra it says "students who have scored more than 50 in all subject". the "in all subject" part requires grouping, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

```
case class Students(rollNo:Int, subject:String, marks:Double)

val students = Vector(Students(1,Math,40),Students(1,English,60), Students(1,Science,55), Students(2,Math,80),Students(2,English,60), Students(2,Science,55),Students(3,Math,40),Students(3,English,60), Students(3,Science,30))

val studentsGroup = students.groupBy(_.rollNo)
val ans = studentsGroup.filter(_.2.forall(_.marks>50))
println(ans)
//output Map(2 -> Vector(Students(2,Math,80.0), Students(2,English,60.0), Students(2,Science,55.0)))
```

Comment: it is just returning list of booleans. List(true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false)

Comment: @user3287034 i have edited the answer try this one it will give you the answer as you want.

Comment: @user3287034 can you add desired output in the question? so i can modify the answer

Comment: Hi Raman, is it possible for you to explain me how to do the same in spark dataset. I am trying to do the same from 2 days but not possible and not able to put any more questions.

Comment: @user3287034 i think spark has the same functions where you stucked?

Comment: how to do it in spark dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a case class `Students`, something like the following will give you a map keyed by the students ID for students with all scores above 50.

```
case class Students(id:Int, subject:String, score:Int)
val result = scores.groupBy(_.id).filter(_._2.forall(_.score > 50))
```

Comment: how to do it in spark dataset?